# Данные из файла в массив

Tags: pascal

Есть файл с данными, к примеру, INPUT.TXT. Его содержимое:

> 5 3 4 5 1 5 2

Задача в том, что-бы вытащить эти числа из файла и каждое число положить в элемент массива. Также, элементы массива нужно сложить и вывести среднее арифметическое.

Answer (score 1):

Вторая строка в поиске гугла + две переменные и два сложения....

```
Uses Crt, Dos; 
Var F: Text; 
    V: Int;
    cnt: Int;
    sum: Int;

Begin
 {Получаем имя файла из командной строки}
 Assign(F, ParamStr(1)); {или укажите жестко, второй аргумент}
 Reset(F); 
 While Not EOF(F) Do
 Begin
  Read(F, V);
      sum:=sum+1;      
  cnt:=cnt+1;
 End; 
    writeln(sum/cnt);
End.
```

Comment: sum:=sum+1;  Исправьте __1__ на __V__; Да и потом - просили же массив.

Comment: Спасибо, я искал не мог найти, видимо не правильно искал, только начал Паскаль изучать)

Comment: заканчивай изучать его =) джаву учи )))

Comment: Чего это заканчивать-то? Delphi+asm не самая слабая связка и рынок не простаивает, к слову.